# How to store the number of times the button is pressed in AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The number would increased by 1 when I pushed the button.

However, after refreshing the screen, the number shows 「０」.

I want to show the number where it left off before refreshing.

Where should I fix to store the value in AsyncStorege correctly?
Could you give some advice please?

```
export default class ApplauseButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      applause: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const applauseCount = parseInt(AsyncStorage.getItem('applause'),10);
      this.setState({applaused:applauseCount});
  };

  handlClick() {
    const countapplause = this.state.applause + 1;
     AsyncStorage.setItem('applause', countapplause.toString()).then(() => {
       this.setState({ applause: this.state.applause + 1});
     });
   };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title=""
          onPress={() => {
            this.handlClick()
          }} />
        <Text style={styles.count}>
          {this.state.applause}/
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to set the state in `componentDidMount`

Comment: Should it be await AsyncStorage.setItem(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there are two things you should change:

1.Set the state when you get the count from the AsyncStorage.

2.you are setting the previous value in AsyncStorage instead store the incremented value.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  getcount();
};

 getcount = async () => {
  let count = '';
  try {
    count = await AsyncStorage.getItem('applause') || '0';
     count = parseInt(count,10);
     this.setState({applause:count})
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}


handlClick= async ()=> {
         const count = this.state.applause + 1;
        try{
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('applause', count.toString());
           this.setState({ applause: count});
       }
       catch(error){
        console.log(error.message);
       }
    };
```

Comment: I changed my code following your instruction, but nothing changed.
Did I miss other thing?

Comment: sorry , i didn't get you

Comment: I changed  the code, but the number still show 「0」after refreshing.

Comment: can you create a working model on sandbox or something

Comment: @Ywzx  i have edited the answer once try doing this way

Comment: I'm not familiar with sandbox,,, How about github? https://github.com/Yosuke-Aramaki/Sample1

Comment: yeah no problem but did you try my latest  edited code ??

Comment: I tried it right before, but the number still show 0 after refreshing.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Welcome, What was the issue ?

Comment: After I change the code below, that worked!
componentDidMount = async () => {
  let count = '';
  try {
    count =  ............